# Uploading via FTP to Unix server scrambles file names

Tags: c#, unix, ftp

I'm trying to upload files via ftp to a UNIX server. However, when I do this, the file names are scrambled.

For example, test.txt becomes PAVXVC~8.TXT.

I'm using the PutFile method in the Rebex.Net.Sftp class. I'm doing this in the following way:

```
sftp.PutFile(file.FullName, destinationPath);
```

On a Linux server, when the destination path is of the form /FileName, or Path/FileName, then the name of the file gets scrambled and it is just placed at the root of the directory. However, on a Windows server, this works as expected.

I'm unsure about the reasons behind this - for example, is it to do with the encoding (currently ASCII)?

Are there any obvious checks?

Comment: Why did you add the c# tag, do you upload with your own c# program? Can you show the code you use? Can you compare the results with an upload using other programs?

Comment: What FTP client are you using? Do you have client-side or server-side log? Either post your code (if you are using your own FTP code) or move the question to [su] (as it's off-topic here, if you are not programming FTP).

Comment: Sure - I've added a few more details, there's really not much to it. We do not have access to the client-side log, the client server is maintained by a third party, and they are not being especially helpful. I'm wondering if there is anything that is obviously different the way this works on Unix environments. It could just be a firewall issue, but again, I do not have that much information.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your ftp client is providing to the server the old DOS-style short version of the filename. If you'd rather not try a different ftp client, you could specify the remote filename yourself:

```
put localfilename remotefilename
```

Comment: That would make sense for the larger file names, however the DOS short names do not correspond with what I am seeing. Moreover, cmd dir /x returns test.txt as the short name, no alterations, etc. So I do not think this is the issue.

Comment: You're right, good point. It would still be interesting to see what happens when you specify the destination name explicitly since it might narrow down where the problem is. Are you using wildcards or just putting one file a time?